# Heroku - foreman start fails with no such option: --noinput;

Tags: django, heroku, foreman

Hi Im having trouble getting foreman to start my app **locally**... although the application runs when I used `python manage.py runserver`

when I use the command

```
foreman start
```

I get this output:

```
(venv)MacBook-Pro:staging macbook$ foreman start
12:25:08 web.1     | started with pid 15160
12:25:09 web.1     | Usage: manage.py collectstatic [options] 
12:25:09 web.1     | 
12:25:09 web.1     | Collect static files in a single location.
12:25:09 web.1     | 
12:25:09 web.1     | manage.py: error: no such option: --noinput;
12:25:09 web.1     | process terminated
12:25:09 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

this is my procfile ( which has something to do with this issue )

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; gunicorn wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

this all works fine when pushed to Heroku... just not locally on my machine.

when I pull the collecstatic part out - it runs fine with gunicorn like this:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

so it appears to be the python manage.py collecstatic --noinput that it doesn't like... however if I run that part manually in the directory collecstatic works fine.

Here's my .bash_profile

```
# {{{
# Node Completion - Auto-generated, do not touch.
shopt -s progcomp
for f in $(command ls ~/.node-completion); do
  f="$HOME/.node-completion/$f"
  test -f "$f" && . "$f"
done
# }}}

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
```

my configuration also is Im running virtualenvwrapper and installed all of this via Brew and PIP...

Comment: Which version of Django are you running locally? Also, why are you running collectstatic on your local env? Aren't you serving static assets locally?

Comment: Django 1.4.1 - and I just pulled the repo down from git as Im secondary collaborator so Im not sure yet of all the settings and procfile...just trying to get it working locally and this is the issue I ran into so far.

Comment: Weird. Have you tried updating the Heroku toolbelt?

Comment: yes i just recently did that - heroku update -  heres the output...Updating from 2.33.5... done, nothing to update

Comment: btw when I pull out the manage.py collect static --noinput -- the rest of it runs fine ( gunicorn etc )

Comment: What about a manual `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`?

Comment: It works manually - output = 0 static files copied, 359 unmodified. ( and previously it actually collected them )

Comment: It looks like your shell doesn't like the `--noinput` flag with the following `;`. Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Not sure - I posted my .bash_profile up in the original comment as well...

Comment: shit..I reinstalled heroku toolbelt manually ( download from site ) and now it works... but now my virtualenvwrapper is broken.. or at least the workon command doesn't work. sigh.  at least forman is now working!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled Heroku Toolbelt from download at site rather than upgrade via command line...now foreman works.